# Is it possible to use Selenium with C# windows Form that contains a WebBrowser object?

Tags: .net, winforms, selenium, webbrowser-control

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Selenium with a C# Windows Form 
that contains a WebBrowser object.

I'm using selenium
and I'm able to create test cases with the Selenium script record; I'm 
just trying to pinpoint whether or not I can export the C# code and 
have it all run within a C# environment.  I appreciate any thoughts or 
explanations.

**update**
I got to the point to have Selenium open the WinForm which contains the WebBrowser Component. However from there my test won't execute. Looks like it doesn't understand selenium command. I don't see any error messages being thrown though. hmmm

The thing is `winformWithWebBrowserTest`.exe which opens winForm with webbrowser is opened.
But nothing happens. Below code is the one that fires up the .exe

**test code (Selenium command)**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Class2
    {
        private ISelenium selenium;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {

            selenium = new DefaultSelenium
                ("localhost", 4444, "*custom C:\\Users\\m-tak\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\winformWithWebBrowserTest\\winformWithWebBrowserTest\\bin\\Release\\winformWithWebBrowserTest.exe", "http://www.livemocha.com");

            selenium.Start();
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheUntitledTest()
        {
            //nothing here gets executed :(
            Console.WriteLine("foobar front");
            selenium.Open("/");
            Console.WriteLine("foobar");
            selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
            selenium.Open("/users/logout");
            selenium.Open("/users/login");


        }

    }
}
```

**.exe**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           //this gets executed always......
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
            HtmlElement scriptOne = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptOne.DomElement;
            element.text = "function sayHello() { " + 
                "alert('hello');" +
                " }" ;
            head.AppendChild(scriptOne);
            webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");


        }
        //getter setter..... 
        public WebBrowser getWebBrowser() 
        {
            return this.webBrowser1;

        }
        public void setWebBrowser(WebBrowser wb) 
        {
            this.webBrowser1 = wb;
        }

        //just address bar
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        //just address bar
        private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != e.Url.ToString())
            {
                textBox1.Text = e.Url.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I made my test simple so now I don't use NUnit. I've created C# console app just to run the c# .exe file. But in my console it would output `"--1--"` and "`--2--"` only..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using Selenium;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("-- 1---");
            ISelenium selenium;


            selenium = new DefaultSelenium
                ("localhost", 4444, "*custom C:\\Users\\m-takayashiki\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\winformWithWebBrowserTest\\winformWithWebBrowserTest\\bin\\Release\\winformWithWebBrowserTest.exe", "http://www.livemocha.com");

            Console.WriteLine("-- 2---");

            selenium.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("-- 3---");


            selenium.Open("/");
            selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
            selenium.Open("/users/logout");
            selenium.Open("/users/login");


            Console.WriteLine("test test test");

            //tear down
            selenium.Stop();

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I checked RC log:

```
15:40:35.379 DEBUG [13] org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext - Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
15:40:35.380 DEBUG [13] org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler - req: POST /selenium-server/driver/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:4444
Content-Length: 247
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: keep-alive

15:40:45.408 DEBUG [13] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - waiting for window 'null' local frame 'null' for 1790 more secs
15:40:45.408 DEBUG [13] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - waiting for condition for 1000 more ms
15:40:45.945 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - got condition? : false
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this with selenium, but I did the same thing with WatiN when I wanted to automate InfoPath. The approach that I took was as follows:

1. Kill off all the processes that have that name in my case it was "infopath"

   ```
   foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("infopath"))
   {    
     proc.Kill();
   }
   ```
2. Launch your test application call Process.GetProcessesByName to get all the process id's then get the window handle of the first as there should only be one process running.

   ```
   Process[] updatedInfopathProcessList = Process.GetProcessesByName("infopath");
   if (updatedInfopathProcessList[0].Id == 0)
   {
       throw new ApplicationException("No Infopath processes exist");
   }
   infopathProcessId = updatedInfopathProcessList[0].Id;
   infopathHwnd = updatedInfopathProcessList[0].MainWindowHandle;
   ```
3. Now that I had the window handle, I get the IHTMLDocument2 to automate against with WatiN.

   ```
   InternalHTMLDOMDocument = IEDom.IEDOMFromhWnd(this.hWnd);
   ```

The real rubber hits the road in the IEDom class ... code is below ...

```
    namespace ItiN
    {
        public class IEDom
        {

            internal static IHTMLDocument2 IEDOMFromhWnd(IntPtr hWnd)
            {
                Guid IID_IHTMLDocument2 = new Guid("626FC520-A41E-11CF-A731-00A0C9082637");

                Int32 lRes = 0;
                Int32 lMsg;
                Int32 hr;

                //if (IsIETridentDlgFrame(hWnd))
                //{
                    if (!IsIEServerWindow(hWnd))
                    {
                        // Get 1st child IE server window
                        hWnd = NativeMethods.GetChildWindowHwnd(hWnd, "Internet Explorer_Server");
                    }

                    if (IsIEServerWindow(hWnd))
                    {
                        // Register the message
                        lMsg = NativeMethods.RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
                        // Get the object
                        NativeMethods.SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, lMsg, 0, 0, NativeMethods.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, ref lRes);
                        if (lRes != 0)
                        {
                            // Get the object from lRes
                            IHTMLDocument2 ieDOMFromhWnd = null;
                            hr = NativeMethods.ObjectFromLresult(lRes, ref IID_IHTMLDocument2, 0, ref ieDOMFromhWnd);
                            if (hr != 0)
                            {
                                throw new COMException("ObjectFromLresult has thrown an exception", hr);
                            }
                            return ieDOMFromhWnd;
                        }
                    }
               // }
                return null;
            }

            internal static bool IsIETridentDlgFrame(IntPtr hWnd)
            {
                return UtilityClass.CompareClassNames(hWnd, "Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame");
            }

            private static bool IsIEServerWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
            {
                return UtilityClass.CompareClassNames(hWnd, "Internet Explorer_Server");
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry this is not for selenium, but it is how I solved the problem for WatiN so I hope it can help. The code is here http://itin.codeplex.com/, and I also think that this has been added to WatiN as well.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code, I'll try apply this approach with Selenium.

Comment: @masato-san Greetings from the year 2015. Did you ever manage to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it would work as long Selenium can inject JS into the browser component. You would need to use the *custom command and pass in the executable that you want Selenium to start up and then it will try do what you want.

Comment: http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/ very interesting to read about selenium. So looks like only selenium2 can handle .NET implementation

Comment: I was the .NET maintainer so only show cased that code. IT does .NET, Java, Ruby and Python

Comment: Also looks like someone has done this before if my understanding is correct. http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/02/21/automated-ui-testing-with-project-white.aspx

Comment: wait.. project white doesn't use Selenium.. its just automation framework for winform

Comment: Project White is built on top of Microoft's UI Automation stack that shipped with WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can, but you might have to use [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).  It has a .Net version of the Selenium API.

Comment: Yes, I know selenium test can be written using C# but I'm not sure if the selenium can talk to winForm in someway and the winForm can understand the command to execute some action automatically like button click etc

Comment: All you would have to do is call whatever you needed in the C# code.  If you wanted to have a winform button get used then all you would need to do is use buttonname.PerformClick(). If there was a specific function that you wanted to run it should be a easy as calling that function.

Comment: So you mean, selenium is just for executing and then rest of C# code is ... just c# code ??? I mean not using Selenese like "selenium.open("/somepath")" cuz selenese seems not working for me.

Comment: You should be able to use selenese just fine.  How are you running the test?  NUnit? Main function?

Comment: i'm runningt thru NUnit, does that make difference??? The thing is though, say, client created clientCSharp.exe and my test code written in cs has to recognize the webbrowser control in clientCSharp.exe for automation.

Comment: When you run the test are you seeing the debug/log window for selenium RC?

Comment: No, I haven't.. in fact, I didn't know RC has log. I'll check it out

Comment: I updated my question with RC log info. Looks like Selenium is not recognizing the WebBrowser ? (window is null)

Answer (score 1):

We hacked the selenium webdriver code slightly to attach to an embedded IE instance inside a windows app. http://bradbax.blogspot.ca/2013/07/driving-embedded-wpf-browser-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it at the moment but it should be possible with a remote debugging browser instance like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069612/13163366).

A other option would be to use [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver), it's pretty simular to Selenium because it uses the same web protocol.

There is a [good guide](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/automate-windows-desktop-apps-winappdriver/) from AutomateThePlanet how to use it.