# Selenium with a C# Windows Form that contains a WebBrowser

Tags: c#, selenium

I have been looking all over the internet for resources that explaining a way of using selenium with a C# Windows Form that contains a WebBrowser object. We have this project that requires implementing selenium to interact with the Embedded webBrowser.

Any resource would be useful. 
I have looked into this but it gets no where.
[Is it possible to use Selenium with C# windows Form that contains a WebBrowser object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090440/is-it-possible-to-use-selenium-with-c-sharp-windows-form-that-contains-a-webbrow)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible to use selenium with your own browser. Selenium can be used only for browsers that selenium support (opera, safari, firefox, chrome, phantomjs, ie, etc)

But you can use native c# functionality for this. There is possible to do some actions as clicking on elements and some another, but its pretty poor.

Comment: I haven't tested it at the moment but it should be possible nowadays: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069612/13163366