# Selenium Webdriver and Embedded Browser in a Winform - How to connect web_driver instance?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I need to connect/create an instance of Selenium Webdriver to web content that my application under test opens in a Winform.

My test framework opens the Winform application with CodedUI, and further test steps cause the Winform application to open another Winform window that has a browser embedded in it.  I need to create or tie a Selenium instance to this embedded browser content.  It's using WebViewer/Edge in the embedded area.

Note - Not yet ready to move to WinAppDriver, if ever.

Answer (score 5):

Resolved this.  I found out that the web pane is an object called a WebView2.

Automating inside it requires the application to be launched in a special way:

```
Dim AppPath As String = "[full path to your app and its name].exe"

Dim edgeOptions As New EdgeOptions

edgeOptions.UseChromium = True
edgeOptions.UseWebView = True

edgeOptions.DebuggerAddress = "localhost:9222"

Dim AppStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(AppPath)
         
AppStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
AppStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS") = "--remote-debugging-port=9222"

Diagnostics.Process.Start(AppStartInfo)
```

You also need:

- Selenium Support and Selenium Webdriver version 4.0.0-rc3 installed in the projects
- msedgedriver from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

And finally in your automation code, when the window with WebView2 in it finally appears, you need to run this code to tie selenium webdriver to the WebView2 pane:

```
Dim driver As String = "[path to:]msedgedriver.exe"

Dim edgeOptions As New EdgeOptions

edgeOptions.UseChromium = True
edgeOptions.UseWebView = True

edgeOptions.DebuggerAddress = "localhost:9222"

Dim WebDriver = New EdgeDriver(EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".", driver), edgeOptions)
```

Comment: I am facing same type of issue. Our application launches in a separate window (not browser) like a normal windows application, and inside content whatever displayed are web forms and controls. The outer layer is showing as **chrome_RenderWidgetHost**.
I tried to follow your answer, this opens up a new browser and handles the same; but in my case need to attach the driver to the widget application window. Any suggestions or is it possible? @ORNS